# SQL Query Turn field elements into columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this

```
[Serial Number]   [EventNumber]    [DateTimeStamp]     [DataElement]  [DataValue]
XXXX1                 1          7/7/2013 10:00 AM        Height         62
XXXX1                 1          7/7/2013 10:00 AM        Mass           12
XXXX1                 1          8/3/2013 3:00 PM         Length         13
XXXX1                 1          8/3/2013 3:00 PM         Width          60
XXXX1                 2          10/10/2013 10:00 AM      Height         22
XXXX1                 2          10/10/2013 10:00 AM      Mass           21
XXXX1                 2          10/12/2013 10:00 AM      Length         7
XXXX1                 2          10/12/2013 11:00 AM      Width          67
```

Workers in the factory enter the data through a web interface and it ends up in this table. The table contains hundreds of serial numbers and each serial number can have up to 19 or more events. Each event is some parameters that are measured. After the measurements are taken some modifications are done and the measurements get taken again for a sequential event.

I would like to create a table that looks like this for one specific serial number through SQL query

```
[Serial Number]  [EventNumber] [Height]    [Mass]    [Width]   [Lenght]
XXXX1                  1           62          12       13        20
XXXX1                  2           10          etc     etc
XXXX1                  3           etc
XXXX1                  4           etc
```

I know I need to use the pivot, but I can't necessarily come up with correct SQL code.

Note: The data used in this example is made up, but the structure is all the same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already looked at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(t.DataValue) AS SumOfDataValue
SELECT t.[Serial Number], t.EventNumber
FROM Table1 AS t
GROUP BY t.[Serial Number], t.EventNumber
PIVOT t.DataElement;
```

Let me know if any problems.